# How to require non-blank text on an Alert Input Dialog

Tags: android

I would like to retrieve user input via an Alert Dialog... is there any way to make it so that the user cannot press Ok if the EditText is blank? I mean require that he type something in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use textchangeListener to achieve this in afterTextChange method check text of editText, and according to length set enable or disable Ok button, as follows:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                                //XXX do something
                                if(editText.getText().length()>0)
                                     btnOk.setEnabled(true);
                                else
                                     btnOk.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
int after) {
                                //XXX do something
                        }
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                            //XXX do something
                    }
    });
```

Comment: this requires a custom layout? or is there a way to access the AlertDialog default ok button?

Comment: you can do with dialog's default button also: alertDialog.getButton(whichButton).setEnabled(enabled);

Comment: **for future readers:** there is a problem getButton() returns null in API 7 (fixed in 2.2) before show() is called. Solution call show() first... http://goo.gl/amxhY , http://goo.gl/UbGNg

Answer (score 1):

use customized layout for alert dialog.  ex:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name);
            //sample for getting view id...

            //TextView dialogbody=(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogbody);
```